# Java: Getting time with currentTimeMillis() as a long, how do I output it with X decimal place accuracy?

Tags: java, time, long-integer

I have a long that represents `System.currentTimeMillis()`. I then took another measurement of the time into a long var later in my code. I subtracted the two but now want to see that time to 3 decimal places.

Currently I use `%d` to format my output when printing the long var and get only non-decimal values.

Comment: currentTimeMillis() - currentTimeMillis() = a figure expressed in milliseconds without decimals.  Do you want to see a figure in seconds with decimals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`long` is a whole number. It doesn't have decimal places.  Do you mean you want to see seconds to three decimal places?

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
System.out.printf("Took %.3f%n", time/1e3);
```

You can do the same with nanoTime, but it is still a whole number.  If you want to see decimal places you need to divide by 1e3 (micro-seconds) or 1e6 (milli-seconds) or 1e9 (seconds)

Answer (score 5):

You need to divide the number by `1000.0` and then display it using `"%.3f"`. So something like

```
String.format("%.3f", number / 1000.0)
```

You need to divide by a `double` because you want a double. If you did divide by an `int` then it would round to the nearest int. You can't use `%d` because it is only used for displaying integers. You have to use `%f` for floats and doubles.