# Datatype for milliseconds

Tags: java, android, time

I´ve a time measure system in my app and where I have my milliseconds in a `LONG` datatype.

Now, I want them to convert into seconds, that´s easy by dividing through 1000.

What I need is decimal place for the milliseconds. How do I get it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Getting time with currentTimeMillis() as a long, how do I output it with X decimal place accuracy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547255/java-getting-time-with-currenttimemillis-as-a-long-how-do-i-output-it-with-x)

Answer (score 6):

```
long seconds = timeInMillis/1000;
long milliseconds = timeInMillis%1000;

double timeInSeconds = ((double)seconds) + (((double)milliseconds)/1000.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html). It has clean methods to handle such conversions. Like convertion from milliseconds to seconds and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I´m so stupid.

Just took the datatype `Double`.

Comment: or [float](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).